# Do we need to declared the variable "x" in a "FOR EACH x IN y" loop?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Im working with VBA in MS ACCESS 2013.

One of my Modules has a `For Each fld In rs.Fields` and does not require me to declare the variable `fld`.

On my new function i have the same `For Each fld In rs.Fields`, but when i do not include the deceleration `Dim fld As Object` i get the following error:

> "Variable not defined"

[image: Compiler Error when the <fld> variable is not declared]

From what I read in the API, and from my experience previously, I was under the impression that this is not required.

## So what's causing this ERROR???

When i do declare the `fld` variable as an object, it compiles, but throws the error:

> "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method"

[image: Object Does not support property or method]

I will include the code just in case:

```
Public Function AcademicStaff()
    Dim my_xl_app As Object, my_xl_worksheet As Object, my_xl_workbook As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    r = 5
    c = 1
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim qryStr As String
    qryStr = "SELECT tblFaculty.[Full Name], tblFaculty.Rank, tblFaculty.[Hire Date], tblFaculty.[Continuing Appointment], tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.Status, tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.[Year of Registration or Application], tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.AQ, tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.EE, tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.PP FROM tblFaculty INNER JOIN tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg ON tblFaculty.[Faculty ID] = tblCurrentProfessionalEngineeringReg.[Faculty ID];"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qryStr)

    Dim fn1 As String, fn2 As String, fn3 As String, fn4 As String, fn5 As String, fn6 As String, AQ As String, PP As String, EE As String

    fn1 = "Full Name"
    fn2 = "Rank"
    fn3 = "Hire Date"
    fn4 = "Continuing Appointment"
    fn5 = "Status"
    fn6 = "Year of Registration or Application"
    AQ = "AQ"
    PP = "PP"
    EE = "EE"


    Set my_xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set my_xl_workbook = my_xl_app.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Do While Not (rs.EOF)
            For Each fld In rs.Fields

                With my_xl_workbook.Sheets(1)
                    If fld.Name = fn1 Then ''''''''''''''''''''''''"Full Name"
                     c = 1
                     Debug.Print "r= " & r
                     Debug.Print "c= " & c
                     Debug.Print "Val = " & fld.Value & "[Type: " & TypeName(fld.Value)
                    .Cell(r, c).Value = fld.Value
                     GoTo gotoNextField

                    ElseIf fld.Name = fn2 Then ''''''''''''''''''''''''"Rank"
                     GoTo gotoNextField '''''''''''''''''''''''' Review Rank Entry ********************
                     c = 2
                    .Cell(r, c).Value = fld.Value

                     GoTo gotoNextField

                    ElseIf fld.Name = fn3 Then ''''''''''''''''''''''''"Hire Date"
                    c = 3
                    Debug.Print "DATE FORMAT: " & Format(fld.Value, "dd-mm-yy")
                        .Cell(r, c).Value = fld.Value
                     GoTo gotoNextField

                    ElseIf fld.Name = fn4 Then ''''''''''''''''''''''''"Continuing Appointment"
                    c = 4
                    If fld.Value Then
                        .Cell(r, c).Value = "Y"
                        Else
                        .Cell(r, c).Value = "N"
                        End If
                    GoTo gotoNextField

                    ElseIf fld.Name = fn4 Then ''''''''''''''''''''''''"Status"
                    c = 5
                    .Cell(r, c).Value = fld.Value
                    GoTo gotoNextField

                    End If

                    End With


gotoNextField:
            Next
        r = r + 1
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop


    my_xl_workbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    my_xl_app.Quit
    Set my_xl_app = Nothing
    Set my_xl_workbook = Nothing
    Set my_xl_worksheet = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you'll always have to declare every variable. Maybe use `Dim fld As Field` because it's a recordset field?

Comment: Either do as @JenZzz said or as a `Variant`. Also, note the top of your module file, does it have `Option Explicit`? That is what enforces declaration of variables (which is always a good idea).

Comment: @JeremyCook Yes you were correct, it was the key word `Option Explicit` forcing me to declare `fld`'s. And it was the answer from Lord Peter that was causing the run-time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your variable properly declared your run-time error is coming from Excel. The Sheet object in Excel does not have a Cell (singular) member. You need to change it to:-

```
    .Cells(r,c).Value = fld.Value
---------^
```

(and you may change your recordset and field dimensioning to DAO.recordset or ADODB.recordset etc, just in case you have references set to both libraries - they have different properties.)